# YouTube's Data APi V3 search.list returns no upcoming video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Until last week my API calls returned my upcoming videos but since yesterday it is returning an empty list.

What I'm doing wrong?

Call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=MY_KEY&part=id%2Csnippet&channelId=UCeMz6kO4knQnUWwuzRpjEFA&order=date&type=video&maxResults=5&eventType=upcoming
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with both live and upcoming event types.